# How to calculate dictionaries of lists using pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have two strings in Python3.x, which are defined to be the same length:

```
string1 = 'WGWFTSJKPGP'
string2 = 'DORKSRQKYJG'
```

I am also given an integer which is meant to represent the "starting index" of `string2`. In this case, `start_pos = 51`.

The goal is to create a dictionary based on the indices. So, `string1` begins at `0`, `string2` begins at `51`. The dictionary "converting" these coordinates is as follows:

```
{0: 51, 1: 52, 2: 53, 3: 54, 4: 55, 5: 56, 6: 57, 7: 58, 8: 59, 9: 60, 10: 61}
```

which can be constructed (give the variables above) with:

```
convert_dict = {i: i + start_pos for i, _ in enumerate(string1)}
```

I currently have this data in the form of a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'column1':['MXRBMVQDHF', 'LJNVTJOY', 'LJNVTJOY', 'LJNVTJOY', 'WHLAOECVQR'], 'column2':['DPBVNJYANX', 'UWRAWDOB', 'PEKUYUQR', 'WPMLFVFZ', 'CUTQVWHRIJ'], 'start':[79, 31, 52, 84, 18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df)
#       column1     column2  start
# 0  MXRBMVQDHF  DPBVNJYANX     79
# 1    LJNVTJOY    UWRAWDOB     31
# 2    LJNVTJOY    PEKUYUQR     52
# 3    LJNVTJOY    WPMLFVFZ     84
# 4  WHLAOECVQR  CUTQVWHRIJ     18
```

There are multiple entries of the same string in column `column1`. In this case, the dictionary for the coordinates with `LJNVTJOY` should be:

```
{0: [31, 52, 84], 1: [32, 53, 85], 2: [33, 54, 86], 3: [34, 55, 87], 
     4: [35, 56, 88], 5: [36, 57, 89], 6: [37, 58, 90], 7: [38, 59, 91]}
```

I would like to take this DataFrame and calculate similar dictionaries of the coordinates. Such a `.groupby('column1')` statement looks like one should somehow use `.apply()`? I'm not sure how to populate dictionary lists like this...

Here is the correct output (keeping the DataFrame structure). Here the DataFrame `df2` has the column `'new_column'` such that it looks like the following:

```
df2.new_column
0    {0: 79, 1: 80, 2: 81, 3: 82, 4: 83, 5: 84, 6: ...
1    {0: [31, 52, 84], 1: [32, 53, 85], 2: [33, 54, 86], 3: [34, 55, 87], 4: [35, 56, 88], 5: [36, 57, 89], 6: [37, 58, 90], 7: [38, 59, 91]}
2    {0: 52, 1: 53, 2: 54, 3: 55, 4: 56, 5: 57, 6: ...
Name: new, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
def dict_op(x):
    string1 = x['column1']
    string2 = x['column2']
    start_pos = x['start']
    x['val'] = {i: i + start_pos for i, _ in enumerate(string1)}
    return x

def zip_dict(x):
    b=pd.DataFrame(x)
    return {i:b.loc[:,i].tolist() for i in b.columns }

op = df.apply(dict_op, axis=1).groupby('column1')['val'].apply(list).apply(zip_dict)
print(op)
```

**Output**

```
column1
LJNVTJOY      {0: [31, 52, 84], 1: [32, 53, 85], 2: [33, 54,...
MXRBMVQDHF    {0: [79], 1: [80], 2: [81], 3: [82], 4: [83], ...
WHLAOECVQR    {0: [18], 1: [19], 2: [20], 3: [21], 4: [22], ...
Name: val, dtype: object
```

**Explanation**

The `dict_op` reuses your code to create the dict for every row and then the `.apply(list)` zips the dicts together to form a list of dicts.

The `zip_dict()` then creates the output `dict` out of the interim output.

The last piece that I haven't included is the part where if the length of the list is 1 then you can include the first element only, taking the output from `{0: [79], 1: [80], 2: [81], 3: [82], 4: [83], ...` to `{0: 79, 1: 80, 2: 81, 3: 82, 4: 83, ...`

Answer (score 1):

First apply groupby function to aggregate the "start" column as a list

```
df2 = df.groupby("column1")["start"].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Now, you can write a function to create the new dictionary column

```
def create_dict(row):
    new_dict = {}
    for i, j in enumerate(row["column1"]):
        if len(row["start"]) == 1:
            new_dict[i] = row["start"][0]+i
        else:
            for k in row["start"]:
                if i in new_dict:
                    new_dict[i].append(k + i)
                else:
                    new_dict[i] = [k + i]
    return new_dict
```

Finally, apply this function to all the rows of df2

```
df2["new_column"] = df2.apply(create_dict, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach using a `lambda` and two `zips`.

```
df2 = df.groupby('column1')['start'].agg([('s', list)]).reset_index()
df2['l'] = df.column1.str.len()

df2.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(range(x['l'] + 1), zip(*[range(s, s + x['l'] + 1) for s in x['s']]))), axis = 1)
```

The truncated output of that can be seen here (note that it returns tuples rather than lists):

```
0    {0: (31, 52, 84), 1: (32, 53, 85), 2: (33, 54,...
1    {0: (79,), 1: (80,), 2: (81,), 3: (82,), 4: (8...
2    {0: (18,), 1: (19,), 2: (20,), 3: (21,), 4: (2...
```

First, to cut down on the length of the `apply` step, create a DataFrame with the `column1` values and the associated starting positions. In addition, add a column with the length of `column1` (assuming that the equal length assertion holds).

After that, it's a matter of combining the range of `column1` letter indices (`0` through `len(column1)`, which serves as the keys, and the same range offset by the `start` value(s).

Things get a little dicey with the second `zip` because `[range(s, s + x['l'] + 1) for s in x['s']]` returns something that looks like this (for 'LJNVTJOY'):

```
[[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
 [52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
 [84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92]]
```

When we really want to group the elements aligned vertically, so we use the 'splat' or '[unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)' operator to feed these lists into `zip`. Once we've combined those lists, we have a list of keys and a list (of tuples) of values, which can be `zipped` into a `dict`.